# JavaScript JSON object create using for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I need to create a object like this

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
   {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
   {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
   {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
   {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
];
```

My try is

```
    for (i = 0; i < sales_person_route.length; i++) {
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        {lat: sales_person_route[i].latitude, lng: sales_person_route[i].longitude},
];

}
```

But it's a wrong syntax. But I need to Object like `flightPlanCoordinates`. My lat, lng value available in `sales_person_route`. How to achieve this?

Comment: [Obligatory "There's no such thing as a JSON Object" link](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Take a look at using [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an array before your for statement:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
```

and then for each item in your loop push the corresponding object.

```
 for (i = 0; i < sales_person_route.length; i++) { 
    var salesPersonRoute = sales_person_route[i];
    flightPlanCoordinates.push({ lat: salesPersonRoute.latitude
                               , lng: salesPersonRoute.longitude
    });
}
```

Or you could try this:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = sales_person_route.map(item => {
    return {
        lat: item.latitude, 
        lng: item.longitude
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < sales_person_route.length; i++) {
    let flightPlanCoordinates = {
        lat: sales_person_route[i].latitude,
        lng: sales_person_route[i].longitude
    };
    finalArray.push(flightPlanCoordinates);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object has a great function available, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), made just for this purpose:

```js
var sales_person_route = [
   {latitude: 37.772, longitude: -122.214},
   {latitude: 21.291, longitude: -157.821},
   {latitude: -18.142, longitude: 178.431},
   {latitude: -27.467, longitude: 153.027}
];
var flightPlanCoordinates = sales_person_route.map(r => { 
  return { 
    lat: r.latitude, 
    lng: r.longitude 
  }; 
});
console.log(flightPlanCoordinates);
```

Map iterates over each element in the original array and performs the specified function on the element, returning the result in a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
    var sales_person_route = [{'latitude':'123', 'longitude':'234'}, {'latitude':'123', 'longitude':'234'}];

    for(var i = 0; i < sales_person_route.length; i++) {

        flightPlanCoordinates.push({

            'lat': sales_person_route[i].latitude,
            'lng': sales_person_route[i].longitude,
        });
    }

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates )
```